# Error Parser error in Swagger in query string parameters?

Tags: parameters, swagger, swagger-2.0

Swagger throwing me the following error: "
Parser error bad indentation of a mapping entry
Jump to line 18 ". What is the correct way to add the parameters of a get query?

```
>   parameters:[
>         {
>18:         name: _IdCanal,
>            in: "query",
>            description: "El Id canal es el parametro para identificar cual chatbo se esta utilizando",
>            required: true,
>            type: number
>         },
>         {
>           "name": "_TipoAvance",
>           "in": "query",
>           "description": "El Id canal es el parametro para identificar cual chatbo se esta utilizando",
>           "required": true,
>           "type": "number"
>         },
>         {
>           "name": "_Monto",
>           "in": "query",
>           "description": "El Id canal es el parametro para identificar cual chatbo se esta utilizando",
>           "required": true,
>           "type": "number"
>         },
>         {
>           "name": "_Nombre",
>           "in": "query",
>           "description": "El Id canal es el parametro para identificar cual chatbo se esta utilizando",
>           "required": true,
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>         ],
```

Comment: Please post your complete YAML/JSON file

Answer (score 0):

In line 18 and following the quotation marks are missing:

```
"name": "_IdCanal",
"in": "query",
"description": "El Id canal es el parametro para identificar cual chatbo se esta utilizando",
"required": true,
"type": "number"
```